# What purpose does the Asterisk (*) serve in lint-staged config?

Tags: node.js, lint-staged

I want to use `lint-staged` to run hooks only on staged files in a node.js project. The [docs](https://github.com/okonet/lint-staged) suggest adding the following code to the `package.json` file;

```
{
  "lint-staged": {
    "*": "your-cmd"
  }
}
```

I have also seen the following code elsewhere in another codebase;

```
"lint-staged": {
        "**/*": "prettier --write --ignore-unknown"
    }
```

What purpose does the asterisk(s) serve? I don't suppose it's simply a placeholder. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [the readme says](https://github.com/okonet/lint-staged#filtering-files), those are glob patterns.

```
"*": "your-cmd"
```

will match any file (`*` matches anything by definition)

```
"**/*": "prettier --write --ignore-unknown"
```

[will match](https://mincong.io/2019/04/16/glob-expression-understanding/#the--characters):

- `**` - "≥ 0 characters crossing directory boundaries", followed by
- `/` - A directory boundary, followed by
- `*` - Anything